# PHP - Calling Use from another Function

Tags: php, excel, function

I have a function

```
function readExcel(){
require_once 'SimpleXLSX.php';
use Shuchkin\SimpleXLSX;

if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse('book.xlsx') ) {
    print_r( $xlsx->rows() );
} else {
    echo SimpleXLSX::parseError();
}
```

But when I call readExcel() I got error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "use"
```

Help please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope):

> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped.

A specific example of a `use` inside a function call (what you are attempting to do) is shown as illegal.